# How do load EF class and it's relational classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two tables:

```
MY_TABLE
ID   CODE  VERSION  DESCRIPTION
1    AAA   1        A Test

MY_CHILD_TABLE
ID   CODE  VERSION  COLOR
1    AAA   1        Blue
```

Both are included in my EF model and there is a navigation property setup on both tables.

Now I have the following class to get the data:

```
public static MyData GetMyData(string Code, string version)
{
    using (var context = new Entities())
    {
        return context.MY_TABLE.Where(x => x.MY_CODE == Code && x.MY_VERSION == version).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

This is fine if I want just the data for MY_TABLE.
However I now have a scenario where I want both MY_TABLE and MY_CHILD_TABLE data returned.

How can I return that information back?

 i.e I want to be able to something to the effect of:

```
var result = MyClass.GetMyData("aaa",1);
var color = result.NAV_PROP.Color;
```

If I understand correctly this doesn't work because I am closing the context in the GetMyData method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways  to do that, once you have lazyloading enabled (which is the default setting on EF).

1) Use the extension  "Include"

```
context.Table.Include(t => t.RelatedTable).Where(x => ..Condition..).FirstOrDefault();
```

If your relationship is configured to be a "Required" foreign key relationship, EF will understand you're doing a "Inner Join"

If your relationship is configured to be a "Nullable" (not required), EF will understand you're doing a "Left Join".

2) Select the related data using a .Select before the data is enumerated.

```
context.Table.Where(x = ..Conditions..).Select(s => 
     new { 
          RelatedTableColumn = s.RelatedTable.Column 
          ...
     }).FirstOrDefault();
```

On this case EF will understand you're doing a "Inner Join" like using "Include", but, it will only return your "Selected" columns, which results in better performance for bigger queries.

**Edit 1**

Ps*: If you can't access ".Include" extension, just add:

```
 using System.Data.Entity;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have navigation properties, just include them:

```
return context.MY_TABLE.Include(x=>x.MY_CHILD_TABLEProperty).Where(x => x.MY_CODE == Code && x.MY_VERSION == version).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I do not have a value for x inside my Include method.

Comment: you said that you have navigation properties. show us your ef classes structure

Comment: @JDS add the reference:   using System.Data.Entity;